# Unity2D Visual Problems

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a turret that auto-shoots bullets , fairly simple and not complex, but I have some visual problems. Like in the Editor while Play mode is active the bullet spawn and is visible , but when I go in that place in play mode the bullet is invisible (the bullet applies the damage to the Player but it is not here).

Some footage of the problem:  https://gyazo.com/899f4c60f7d3e0fc943c104bba7c2831

Comment: Your camera could be too close or far away, culling the bullet. The bullet could also be on a layer that the camera isnt rendering.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I tried something about this culling , but i didn't got any progress.

Comment: Check your `Cliping Planes` in the [`Camera` settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) and compare them to the bullets position

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the inspector for the bullet and your camera in play mode? That would help a lot.

Comment: Camera Inspector :https://gyazo.com/a50e7d2a6d252ccb4efbc52f9cd5ee57
Bullet Inspector : https://gyazo.com/d8448cfa1ffa2387c87d4837f0011689
but the bullet is cloned , is ok if i show you the bullet prefab? like the image is about the prefab

Comment: Have you tried setting the `order in layer` on the prefab's Sprite Renderer to 1000 or -1000? While the game is playing, can you pause it and show a screenshot of one of the bullets?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible answers:

1. set the canvas to Screen Space - Camera, and set the Render Camera to Main Camera.

[linke to the full artical](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1057863/help-sprite-showing-up-in-scene-but-not-in-game.html)

2. fix the possition of the srite and the canvas

[link to the full artical](https://answers.unity.com/questions/783178/sprite-not-visible.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help! 
IT WORKED!
I find out that , my turret Z's was like -68 and the camera was like -10, and i randomly entered the 3D View of my scene and i noticed that my Turret was like 10 kilometers away from the actual position from the editor!